# Does Windows Store App Winjs have color picker control?

Tags: html, windows-store-apps, winjs

I need to add color picker to my windows 8 store app using html & javascript, do you know how? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, a standard color picker is not available as you can see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465453.aspx

You can include a purchased or open source option in your application. The biggest issue is that the components may not have the right look that you're needing to match within your application.

Comment: I would add that you're going to find approximately 9,843,570,982,345 JavaScript color picker controls on the web, so I would recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I found the style of most JS color pickers on the web did not really fit well with my windows 8 app design. I created a function that suites my needs, maybe it will help you as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/6GHzP/3/
(the example works only in IE10+ because of the used -ms-grid properties in the css, which are also supported in Windows 8 apps)
Use the function in the following way:

HTML:

```
<div id="the_color_picker"></div>
```

JS:

```
var colorPicker1 = document.getElementById("the_color_picker");
createColorPicker(colorPicker1, 10, 20);

//colorPicker1 is the element in the DOM which will be used to insert the
//colorpicker
//10 is the number of main colors which will result in 10 main colors which
//each will have 10x10 sub colors.
//20 is the size in pixels of every color
```

Please keep in mind this function is not suitable as a very detailed color picker because of the divs that are created for every color. For example createColorPicker(colorPicker1, 255, 1), will show some serious lag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple color picker from
https://github.com/DavidDurman/FlexiColorPicker

Its easy and lightweight.
Working good in windows store apps.

```
<html>
              <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" 
                        src="colorpicker.js"></script>
                <style type="text/css">
                  #picker { width: 200px; height: 200px }
                  #slide { width: 30px; height: 200px }
                </style>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="picker"></div>
                <div id="slide"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  ColorPicker(
                    document.getElementById('slide'),
                    document.getElementById('picker'),
                    function(hex, hsv, rgb) {
                      document.body.style.backgroundColor = hex;
                    });
                </script>
              </body>
            </html>
```